# What is the use of putting extended to true in body parser in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I want to know why do we put the extended value as true in :

```
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the documentation: "The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The "extended" syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a very low effort post, which can be answered by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As [per the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended):

> #### extended
>
> The `extended` option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the `querystring` library (when `false`) or the `qs` library (when `true`). The "extended" syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded. For more information, please [see the qs library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/qs#readme).
>
> Defaults to `true`, but using the default has been deprecated. Please research into the difference between `qs` and `querystring` and choose the appropriate setting.

The primary difference with `qs` is that it supports *nested* data structures, with array/object-like syntax, e.g. `foo[bar]=baz`. If you have a need for that, then using the extended support may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

extended

The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The “extended” syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded. For more information, please see the qs library.

Defaults to true, but using the default has been deprecated. Please research into the difference between qs and querystring and choose the appropriate setting.